# Magento 2.4: How to fix admin page layout broken?

Tags: magento2, page-layouts

I have an issue that after i try to change admin page content this issue happenend. Can anybody show me how to fix this error and how to improve it.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give permission to var generated pub/static using the following command:

```
chmod -R 777 var generated pub/static
```

And run :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer